# Compiler warning in last argument of pcap_loop. Pointing to integer of different size

Tags: c, pointers, tcp, warnings, pcap

I am getting this warning:

```
cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

when attempting to compile my program. This particular piece of code is pretty much lifted from an example TCP connection program and I am just a hobby programmer, so I'm guessing the solution is quite obvious, yet it's driving me mad.

My understanding of the pcap_loop function is that the `u_char *` points to the first argument of the recieve function, right? If that is the case why do get a warning?

As I'm not really sure what's wrong i've included what I believe are the relevant functions in their entirety, and I really hope some of you will find it in you to help me out here.

```
void receive(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *pkthdr, const u_char *buffer)
{
const int one = 1;
int LEN = *args;        
struct ipheader *ip;
struct tcpheader *tcp;

ip = (struct ipheader *)(buffer + LEN);
tcp = (struct tcpheader *)(buffer + LEN + sizeof (struct ipheader));

printf("%d\n", LEN);

printf("Packet received. ACK number: %d\n", ntohl (tcp->tcph_seqnum));
printf("Packet received. SEQ number: %d\n", nthol (tcp->tcph_acknum));
s_seq = nthol (tcp->tcph_seqnum);

send_syn_ack(s_seq, dip, sip, dport, sport);    

sleep(100);
}

void capture()
{
pcap_t *pd;
bpf_u_int32 netmask;
bpf_u_int32 localnet;
char *filter = ("ip dest host %s", dstip);      
char *dev = NULL;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
struct bpf_program filterprog;
int dl = 0, dl_len = 0;

if ((pd = pcap_open_live(dev, 1514, 1, 500, errbuf)) == NULL) 
    {           
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

pcap_lookupnet(dev, &localnet, &netmask, errbuf);
pcap_compile(pd, &filterprog, filter, 0, localnet);
if (pcap_setfilter(pd, &filterprog) == - 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot set pcap filter %s: %s\n", filter, errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

pcap_freecode(&filterprog);
dl = pcap_datalink(pd);

switch(dl) {
    case 1:
        dl_len = 14;
        break;
    default:
        dl_len = 14;
        break;
}       

if (pcap_loop(pd, -1, receive, (u_char *)dl_len) < 0)   /* THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION */
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot get raw packet: %s\n", pcap_geterr(pd));
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

---

Thanks a lot both of you! @pb2q I am a bit confused. when you say:

> you'll need to pass it's address, and make sure that the variable is dynamically allocated or remains in scope >when the callback executes.

I am afraid I'm not sure how that translate into code in this example, and I do not wish for the code to be sloppy, although what has been suggested below seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is expecting a pointer to user data, to pass through to a callback function. Your supplied argument is an integer, and not a pointer, and it will be interpreted as a memory address if it's used in the callback. This isn't what you want.

If you want to pass `dl_len` through to the callback, and be able to look at it's value (looks like it's only ever *14*), you'll need to pass it's *address*, and make sure that the variable is dynamically allocated or remains in scope when the callback executes.

Pass a pointer like so - note the `&`:

```
if (pcap_loop(pd, -1, receive, (u_char *) &dl_len) < 0)
```

Comment: Although it isn't good practise, `dl_len` will still be in scope inside `pcap_loop`.

Comment: "Your supplied argument is an integer, and not a pointer, and it will be interpreted as a memory address". This isn't correct, it has already been cast to a (char *)

Comment: @cmh casting it to a pointer doesn't make it a valid memory address. that's the point of the compiler warning...

Comment: True, but it is never used as such. It just need to be that type to conform to the libpcap API. That isn't why the compiler warning is happening.

Comment: @cmh it's reasonable to assume that the code wants to _use_ the actual value of the variable in the callback. otherwise just pass `NULL`. if so, passing the address is the only way to do this

Comment: I assume he wants to use the address as a value, and not what it points to.

Comment: @cmh which address? `dl_len` is just an integer, **not** an address

Comment: exactly. When `dl_len` is cast to `char*` it is an integer which is interpreted as an address at 14 (in this case). In the callback the address is then cast back to a value (14). The memory location should never accessed (he does need to change `int LEN = *args;` to `int LEN = args;` to achieve this).

Comment: @cmh that's just a sloppy way to pass an argument. I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: I agree that it's sloppy. I'm merely offering an explanation of the warning and offering the path of least resistance to making the given code work. I concede your approach is superior.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding of the pcap_loop function is that the u_char * points
>   to the first argument of the recieve function, right? If that is the
>   case why do get a warning?

Correct. I imagine you are running on x64, the issue is in this piece of code `(u_char *)dl_len)`. You are trying to convert an int (most likely 4 bytes on your platform) to a pointer (most likely 4 bytes on your platform).

The quick fix for your case would be change the type of `dl_len` to a `long`.
A more prefereable solution would be to change `(u_char *)dl_len)` to `reinterpret_cast<char*>(dl_len)`.

You also need to change `int LEN = *args;` to `int LEN = args`, as you don't want to deference this false memory pointer.